# redirect to a view after successful save in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to redirect to a another view after successful save ng-submit form

Controller

```
.factory('Post', function($resource) {
  return $resource('api/add_new_order',{name: "@name", phone: "@phone"});
})
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, Post, Authorization) {

  // Get all posts
  $scope.posts = Post.query();
  // Our form data for creating a new post with ng-model
  $scope.postData = {};
  $scope.newPost = function() {
    var post = new Post($scope.postData);
    post.$save();

  }
$scope.issues = {};
$scope.answer = function(){
    console.log($scope.issues.name);
}
$scope.postData = Authorization;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the routing you are using. Ionic defaul is the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) package. You first have to define different `$state`s in the app's `config` block (-> see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#multiple--named-views)). Then you can inject the `$state` service in your controller and the method [`$state.go()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) will do the 'redirection'.